# Net Core - Receive POST Enum Array to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am learning .NET Core but I cannot figure how to do this.

Having this controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ModelController : Controller
{
        private readonly ModelService _modelService;

        public ModelController(ModelService ModelService)
        {
            _modelService= ModelService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<ListModel>> Get() =>
            _modelService.Get();

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Model> Create(Model newModel)
        {
            _modelService.Create(newModel);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetModel", new { id = model.Id.ToString() }, model);
        }
}
```

This enum:

```
public enum ModelEnum
{
    Property = 0,
    OtherProperty = 1
}
```

And this model:

```
public class Model
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ModelEnum[] theEnum { get; set; }
}
```

How can can I send a request with the property `theEnum`? I am using postman to test it. When I try to do  I receive this a HTTP 400 response with always with errors

First test:
{
"Name": "Test",
"theEnum": [1, 2]
}

First error response

> {
> "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "traceId": "|100e6798-429066a034f499f7.",
> "errors": {
> "$.Clases": [
> "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.Clases | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 21."
> ]
> } }

Second try:

```
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "theEnum": ["Property", "OtherProperty"]
}
```

Second error response:

> {
> "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "traceId": "|100e6799-429066a034f499f7.",
> "errors": {
> "$.Escuelas[0]": [
> "The JSON value could not be converted to Project.ModelEnum[]. Path: $.Escuelas[0] |
> LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 29."
> ]
> } }

So I am wondering, how can I send the value of a Enum type array? Am I doing totally wrong? Maybe the validation messages said what I need but I cannot understand.

Comment: you need to have `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] public enum ModelEnum`

Comment: I guess that StringEnumConverter is a class that I have to write, is this correct?

Comment: No, Its in `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;`

Comment: But I dont think it will work in .net core project. It works with .net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test value for enum 1 and 2. but don't provide enum for value 2
You provide

```
public enum ModelEnum
{
    Property = 0,
    OtherProperty = 1
}
```

Property with value **0** and OtherProperty with value **1**. but test value **1** and **2**.
Add `MyProperty = 2` in `ModelEnum` or test 0,1 value
for secon try you need use StringEnumConverter

Comment: Sorry, cant understand you. Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I understand you. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is about serializing enum array to JSON. 
In Core 3.0+ there is a new serializer that does not yet fully support serialization of enums.
What you need to do is to add [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to your project.
And then call AddNewtonsoftJson() in Startup.ConfigureServices.

Note that enum array converts to digits during serialization

Comment: Thanks for it, I will give it a try